# Sencha Touch component.DataItem to dynamic list

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

Okay, so I have a view that extends `Ext.dataview.component.DataItem'` I have this function

```
onNameButtonTap: function(button, e) {
    var record = this.getRecord();
    console.log("The tid of this record is: " + record.get('tid'));
}
```

I am able to  get an `tid` back from this tap, which I would like to use to load a new view that will use this id to alter the proxy url to get back different data. Here is the view:

```
Ext.define('AIN.view.Headlines.Card', {

extend: 'Ext.NavigationView',
xtype: 'headlineContainer',

config: {

    tab: {
        title: 'Headlines',
        iconCls: 'star',
        action: 'headlinesTab'
    },

    autoDestroy: false,

    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'headlines',
            store: 'Headlines',
        }
    ]
}
});
```

How would I get the url parameter in my store to accept a URL like this one
`'http://mywebsite.com/app-feeds/channels/' + tid`

Thanks for reading, I am new to this and after hours of google searching I can't quite figure this out.

**Update**, this is working for me.

```
var store = Ext.StoreMgr.get('Headlines');

                    store: store.setProxy({
                            type: 'jsonp',
                            url: 'http://awebsite.com/app-feeds/channels/' + tid,
                            reader: {
                                type: 'json',
                                rootProperty: 'nodes',
                                record: 'node'
                            }
                        }).load()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the URL of an `Ext.data.Store` by doing:

```
store.getProxy().setUrl('http://mywebsite.com/app-feeds/channels/' + tid);
```

Note that if you are planning on using this `Store` in multiple areas that use different URLs, you may want to create a new instance of it when you are setting the URL.

Comment: Thanks for the response jprofitt, I just updated my OP with some code that that worked for me. Could you take a quick look and let me know if this is fundamentally wrong way of doing it? (because it probably is). Thanks

Comment: The only thing I would suggest is to do the manipulation of the proxy in a `Controller` rather than a view.